# awk command to select exact word in any field

Tags: shell, awk

I have input file as

```
ab,1,3,qqq,bbc
b,445,jj,abc
abcqwe,234,23,123
abc,12,bb,88
uirabc,33,99,66
```

I have to select the rows which has only 'abc'. And note that abc string can appear in any of the column. Please help me how to achieve this using awk.
Output:

```
b,445,jj,abc
abc,12,bb,88
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use plain grep:

```
grep "(^|,)abc(,|$)" file
```

Or if you have to use awk

```
awk '/(^|,)abc(,|$)/' file
```

Comment: This `awk` was better then mine +1

Answer (score 0):

Through awk,

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="abc") print $0;}}' file | uniq
b,445,jj,abc
abc,12,bb,88
```

OR

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="abc") {print; next}}}' file
b,445,jj,abc,abc
abc,12,bb,88
```

In the above awk command Field Separator variable is set to `,` .  AWk parses the input file line by line. `for` function is used to traverse all the fields in a line. If a value of a particular field is `abc`, then it prints the whole line.

Comment: Wouldn't that print a line multiple times if abc occurs in more than one column?

Comment: To me, `next` does with `awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="abc") {print; next}}}' file`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'gsub(/(^|,)abc(,|$)/,"&")' file
b,445,jj,abc
abc,12,bb,88
```

Based on Beny23s regex.
It does look for `abc` where its starting from `^` start or from a `,` and
ends with a `,` or end of line `$`

Answer (score 0):

Another one using beny23 regex:

```
awk 'NF>1' FS="(^|,)abc(,|$)" infile
```

Not asked but if you feel the need to filter just the lines with one ocurrence:

```
$ cat infile
ab,1,3,qqq,bbc
b,445,jj,abc
abcqwe,234,23,123
abc,12,bb,88
abc,12,bb,abc
uirabc,33,99,66
```

This will be handy:

```
$ awk 'NF==2'   FS="(^|,)abc(,|$)" infile                                                           
b,445,jj,abc
abc,12,bb,88
```

Also possible using Jotne solution:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/(^|,)abc(,|$)/,"&")==1' infile
```